# GWT Button eventlistener designer

Tags: gwt, button, designer, event-listener

For example I took html from a designer which is given below.
How can i add click event which shows alert  from GWT?

```
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td id="nameFieldContainer"><input type="button" name="x" id="x" value="OK" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The button:

```
final Button button = new Button("OK");
```

I dont allow to add button dynamically from GWT by

```
RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(button);
```

I am searching the syntax something like:

```
RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").getWidget(0).addEventListener()
```

Jquery can search the button object from `nameFieldContainer` and
dynamically add click event listener but is it possible in GWT??

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [ClickHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ClickHandler.html). Listeners were deprecated some time ago.

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

edit: I may have misunderstood your question. If you no longer have a reference to the button you could do

```
// code removed because it's really not the best way to solve this problem, and led to confusion...
```

But you'll have to be *very* sure that the element inherits from `HasClickHandlers` -- and you should really just keep a reference to the button, it's much cleaner that way.

Comment: I have a <div id="test"><input type="button" value="OK" /></div>
html tag. is it possible in this case for your solution

Comment: I executed but no action. I used 
((HasClickHandlers)RootPanel.get("test").getWidget(0)).addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.alert('sss');
  }
}

Comment: I noticed you asked another question about this, you really should have just waited for a followup. You should just add the button in GWT and keep a reference to it to add the handler.